# mysql LOAD DATA INFILE not working

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to use mysql LOAD DATA INFILE on command line to load csv file. It neither gives any error nor it loads any data. Can anyone please help me out? I am using following command

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev/__php__/mysql/data.csv'
->             INTO TABLE csvdata
->               FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
->               OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
->               LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
->               IGNORE 1 LINES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Following is my CSV file

```
"emp_id","first_name","last_name","username"
"EMP1","Tibass","Deloris","Tibass1"
```

Regards

Comment: Are you sure about the line feed in your csv? Try the \r\n or \r instead of the \n

Comment: thanks Critian. Line feed was missing in my CSV

Comment: I have answered your question, if you want to close... for the posterity ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably your file line terminator differs from your definition in the `LOAD DATA` statement.

Try the `\r\n` or `\r` instead of the `\n`.